# Deno: How to substitute npm scripts (package.json)

Tags: scripting, npm-scripts, deno

Since it is not necessary to have `package.json` file with deno, how can I as a developer have a similar experience just as we have with `npm scripts` in `package.json`?

Comment: Deno 1.31 presents the support for `package.json`. You can define your scripts as you would in node.js

Answer (score 9):

[velociraptor](https://github.com/umbopepato/velociraptor) may be of help, especially if you want to run arbitrary shell scripts.

It accepts `yaml`, `json` and `ts` script configuration files. The following example illustrates the main features:

```yaml
# scripts.yaml
scripts:

  start: deno run server.ts # Scripts can be simple command strings

  opts:                     # Or objects
    cmd: deno run server.ts
    desc: Starts the server
    tsconfig: tsconfig.json # Deno cli options
    imap: importmap.json
    allow:
      - read
      - net
    env:                    # Env vars
      PORT: 8080

  compact: server.ts        # `deno run` is automatically prepended
                            # when the script starts with a .ts file

  multiple:                 # Lists of commands are executed in series
    - echo one
    - echo two

  concurrent:               # Use the pll property to declare
    pll:                    # concurrent scripts
      - echo one
      - echo two

env:                        # Top level options are sent to all the scripts
  PORT: 3000
allow:
  - write
```

Run `vr` without arguments to see a list of available scripts. To execute a script run:

```sh
$ vr <script name> [additional args]...
# or
$ vr run <script name> [additional args]...
# Additional args are passed to the script
```

ie

```sh
vr start
```

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author

Answer (score 7):

### `deno install`

You can create executable, aliased scripts with [`deno install`](https://deno.land/manual/tools/script_installer).

It will provide a thin shell/cmd wrapper for the specified main module and CLI arguments. Example:

```
deno install --root . -n serve --allow-read --allow-net https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/http/file_server.ts
```

The result is a `serve` script, similar to npm `"scripts": { "serve": ... }`:

```
./bin/serve # run `serve` script (~ npm run serve)
```

If the project's `bin` folder is [added to PATH](https://deno.land/manual/tools/script_installer) environment, the command shortens up to `serve`.

### What `deno install` does

- creates `bin` folder, if not existent
- adds `serve`/`serve.cmd` file with following content (Windows here):

  ```
  % generated by deno install %
  ```

@deno.exe "run" "--allow-read" "--allow-net" "https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/http/file_server.ts" %*
```

- `-n` is the command name used later on (can be [left out](https://deno.land/manual/tools/script_installer))
- `--root` specifies the `bin` root location (otherwise `~/.deno`)
- `-f` option overwrites an existent alias

*Side note*: Any `.js`/`.ts` script is a valid reference - source code location (local/URL) does not matter. If external shell scripts are to be included, you can also run them [inside a subprocess](https://deno.land/manual/examples/subprocess#run-subprocess).

#### Example: Custom `npm run build`

```
// ./scripts/build.ts

// create subprocess
const p = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["deno", "cache", "-r", "--unstable", "main.ts"],
});

await p.status();
```

```
deno install --root . --allow-run scripts\build.ts

./bin/build # execute build script
```

### Built-in `deno` commands

Deno already comes with built-in solutions for common ecosystem tasks, e.g. `bundle`, `fmt`, `test` and `lint` later on (see `deno help`). You can invoke these commands directly - no need to define custom scripts:

```
deno test
deno fmt
deno cache -r main.ts # similar to `npm run build` / `tsc`
# ...
```

Answer (score 6):

I've been working on a solution that mimics the `package.json` scripts sections while adding some Deno specific functionalities.

You need first to install `denox` you can find the instructions here https://github.com/BentoumiTech/denox

Then create a `.deno-workspace` file where you specify your scripts list :

```yaml
scripts:
  # "denox run start" will execute main.ts with example.com networking permissions
  start:
    file: main.ts
    permissions:
      allow-net: example.com
  # "denox run develop" will execute main.ts with localhost networking permissions
  develop:
    file: main.ts
    permissions:
      allow-net: localhost
```

You can then run

1. `$ denox run start`
2. `$ denox run develop`

Comment: Great! How about `--reload`? Where should I specify it?

Comment: @Cea as a temporary solution you can add it in the permissions, I'm currently working on adding support for more options

Comment: @Cea if you need guidance for using the tool I'll be happy to walk you through

Comment: Thanks! Currently working on another project so I could not give a try for the denox, yet. The `--reload` just flashed through my mind and that's why I asked it. I'll let you know if I come across any obstacles.

Comment: how would this incorporate with a pnpm workspace(monorepo) where deno is a project?

Answer (score 5):

[Deno has a built-in Task Runner](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/task_runner) since [v1.20 (released Mar 17, 2022)](https://deno.com/blog/v1.20).

From the docs (as of Oct 16, 2023):

> ## Task Runner
>
> `deno task` provides a cross platform way to define and execute custom
> commands specific to a codebase.
>
> To get started, define your commands in your codebase's [Deno
> configuration file](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/getting_started/configuration_file) under a `"tasks"` key.
>
> For example:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "tasks": {
>     "data": "deno task collect && deno task analyze",
>     "collect": "deno run --allow-read=. --allow-write=. scripts/collect.js",
>     "analyze": "deno run --allow-read=. scripts/analyze.js"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ### Listing tasks
>
> To get an output showing all the defined tasks, run:
>
> ```bash
> deno task
> ```
>
> ### Executing a task
>
> To execute a specific task, run:
>
> ```bash
> deno task task-name [additional args]...
> ```
>
> In the example above, to run the `data` task we would do:
>
> ```bash
> deno task data
> ```

[More details in the Task Runner docs.](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/task_runner) (This link points to the latest version's docs.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own files as denoDept.js

```
export { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@v0.39.0/testing/asserts.ts";
export { green, bold } from "https://deno.land/std@v0.39.0/fmt/colors.ts";
```

And you can add all your dependencies in a single file and use it so it will look like package manager.