# Which build tool is recommended with deno?

Tags: typescript, npm, build, build-tools, deno

I've seen that `deno` does not anymore require `package.json` (supported by npm/yarn) to describe its dependencies.

But for build/run scripts, is `package.json` the proposed descriptor or is there any other build tool/descriptor format that better suits?

Comment: Good question, considering that deno 1.0 just came out. I hope the moderators don't mark your question as too opinion-provoking. I haven't read much guidance on this topic and would love to see a few answers suggesting multiple options.

Comment: I found `deno install` to be a [good replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61763366/deno-how-to-substitute-npm-scripts-package-json/62152367#62152367) for `npm-scripts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deno doesn't support `package.json`.

Currently, there's no built-in nor recommended build tool, but you can use any build tool of your preference: `Make`, `npm scripts`, etc.

---

There are some packages that aim to be a alternative to `npm scripts` for Deno, such as

- [velociraptor](https://github.com/umbopepato/velociraptor)
- [denox](https://github.com/BentoumiTech/denox)

Comment: Very helpful; I wasn't aware of these projects.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Drake (https://deno.land/x/drake), a Make-like task runner I wrote for Deno, inspired by Make, Rake and Jake.

Answer (score 1):

[Deno has a built-in Task Runner](https://deno.land/manual/tools/task_runner) since [v1.20 (released Mar 17, 2022)](https://deno.com/blog/v1.20).

Commands are defined in the project's [Deno configuration file](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/getting_started/configuration_file) under a `"tasks"` key. For example:

```json
{
  "tasks": {
    "data": "deno task collect && deno task analyze",
    "collect": "deno run --allow-read=. --allow-write=. scripts/collect.js",
    "analyze": "deno run --allow-read=. scripts/analyze.js"
  }
}
```

Tasks are listed with `deno task` and run with `deno task task-name [additional-args]...`. E.g. the `data` task would be run with `deno task data`.

[More details in the Task Runner docs.](https://deno.land/manual/tools/task_runner) (This link points to the latest version's docs.)

However, in the v1.26.1 (the latest version as of Oct 16, 2022) docs, the Task Runner is still considered unstable:

> ⚠️ `deno task` was introduced in Deno v1.20 and is unstable.
> It may drastically change in the future.

I don't know which build tool is recommended with Deno, but my hunch is that it would be the Task Runner, at least once it becomes stable, as it's built-in to Deno.